# Comparing two objects in Joi validation (eg. to avoid duplicates)

Tags: joi

I'm using Joi to validate a complex form entry. The form asks for two addresses, `mainContactAddress` and `seniorContactAddress`. I want to validate them to ensure they aren't the same address.

Each address is an object like this:

```
{
    "line1": "123 Some Street",
    "line2": "Some Town",
    "county": "Some County",
    "postcode": "123 ABC",
    "townCity": "City"
}
```

I initially tried this:

```
Joi.ukAddress().invalid(Joi.ref('seniorContactAddress'))
```

(`ukAddress()` is a custom extension I've created which specifies each of the above fields as a required string.)

This doesn't work, because the equality `===` comparison between the two objects returns `false` even when they have the same string values.

I can't see a Joi method to do this. I was hoping to be able to serialise the object (eg. something like `Object.values(mainContactAddress).join(',')` and then compare the resulting strings) but `Joi.ref()` only gives, well, a reference to the object, so I can't call functions against it directly.

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this validation/comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom rule for my extension:

```
{
    // Enforce a unique address compared to the senior contact
    name: 'mainContact',
    validate(params, value, state, options) {
        // Format addresses into a comparable string,
        // making sure we sort them as the stored version
        // is in a different order to the form-submitted one.
        const serialize = address =>
            Object.values(address)
                .sort()
                .join(',');

        const seniorContactAddress = get(
            state.parent,
            'seniorContactAddress',
            []
        );

        if (serialize(seniorContactAddress) === serialize(value)) {
            return this.createError(
                'address.matchesSenior',
                { v: value },
                state,
                options
            );
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

This does feel like an anti-pattern (eg. abusing `state` to look at other values in the Joi object) but it does what I needed.